# script to draw a square where the raster pixels contained within are a certain type and greater than X

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, arcpy

I have a raster containing different pixel values and I am interested in having squares drawn around areas that are at least X m^2 and containing at least Y type of pixels.

The data looks like this, a coverage with the following attributes:

```
OID     Value     Count
0       1         123123
1       2         3342
2       4         2342342
3       5         23423423
4       7         2342323
```

1) I would like to identify (and draw) squares of a certain area around places where there exists at least a certain amount of a pixel value.

2) Squares may overlap.

It would be nice to have the resulting squares output to a separate layer with each square being a unique feature with the following attribute data (number / % of pixels of each value, area, dimensions...).

Comment: Not enough info. Can squares overlap? How many per group?

Comment: question edited.

Answer (score 1):

No script solution

1. Convert raster to binary, assigning 1 to value of interest, 0 for the rest
2. Focal statistics, SUM, with appropriate size square.
3. Raster with value => y to points
4. Buffer of points
5. Polygons from individual buffer extents

Comment: That will generate the # of pixels per square, for sure, but will generate a square of a chosen size for every point in the coverage. I am only looking to generate squares that satisfy the condition of at least X pixels of a certain value, and at least Y area (drawing a square to suit the largest extent that satisfies the minimum % of pixel values of interest). PErhaps I shall amend the question to better clarify that. Thanks for your attempt and it provides at last part of solution :)

Comment: what about the minimum bounding geometry tool (under data management). Anyone have any experience with that or know if it could be rolled into this analysis?